# Stop/Run windows service and building a solution

Tags: .net, msbuild, windows-services, build-process, automation

I'd like to have a script that stops a certain windows service,build or rebuild a solution and runs the service after the build process finished.

Should I use Msbuild for this ? Or is there any other way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [batch file](http://www.allenware.com/icsw/icswidx.htm) that will stop the service, build the solution then start the service:

```
net stop "service name"
<path to msbuild>\msbuild.exe <path to solution file>
net start "service name"
```

See how to [start/stop services](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/864/windows-service-managing-through-command-line/) from the command line, and the msbuild [command line reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx).

Your other option, as mentioned is to use the [MSBuild community tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/). There are many of them - ServiceController is the specific one for your need.

Answer (score 7):

MSBuild is your answer. Controlling the services can be accomplished easily by using the Community Tasks, specifically the service controller task.

http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/

Answer (score 1):

Is the service you are stopping the same executable you are building in the solution?  If so, why not do dynamic code in the service?

Comment: It sounds like you have code that is changing and you want to automate those changes.  Well you can generate new code at run-time using System.Reflection & System.CodeDom.Compiler namespace.

Answer (score 0):

MS build part:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ServiceName>Service</ServiceName>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="PostBuild">
  <Exec Command="net stop $(ServiceName)" ContinueOnError="true" Condition="$(ServiceName)!=''" />
  [. rest of the logic here .]
  <Exec Command="net start $(ServiceName)" ContinueOnError="true" Condition="$(ServiceName)!=''" />
</Target>
```